# Como obter informações dos Satélites através do LocationServices

Tags: android, gps

Existem app's que mostram em quantos satélites seu `GPS` conseguiu se comunicar.

Segue um exmeplo: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chartcross.gpstest

Vi alguns exemplos em que se usa `GpsStatus.Listener` em um `LocationManager`.

Mas hoje em dia ao invés de `LocationManager` estou usando `LocationServices` :

```
 final LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
 LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, request, this);
```

Existe alguma forma de obter as informações do Satélite através do `LocationServices` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que eu saiba não.

O *LocationServices* substitui o *Location Manager* em várias coisas mas no que diz respeito a essa informação ela continua a ser obtida através dele.

Para aplicações que necessitam de correr em versões anteriores à **API24** use as classes [GpsStatus](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.html) e [GpsSatellite](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsSatellite.html).

Basicamente estes são os passos a ter:

- Obter o LocationManager

  ```
  locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  ```
- Registar uma implementação de *GpsStatus.Listener*

  ```
  locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(GpsStatusListener);
  ```
- Na implementação do listener obter um objecto *GpsStatus*, através dele obter um `Iterable<GpsSatellite>` e iterá-lo para obter cada um dos *GpsSatellite* que contém a informação referente ao satélite em questão.

  ```
  GpsStatus gpsStatus = locationManager.getGpsStatus(null);
  Iterable<GpsSatellite> satellites = gpsStatus.getSatellites();
  ```

A partir da ***api24*** deve usar a classe [GnssStatus](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GnssStatus.html).

Exemplo de uso:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocationManager locationManager;
    GnssStatusCallback gnssStatusCallback;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        gnssStatusCallback = new GnssStatusCallback(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.registerGnssStatusCallback(gnssStatusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.unregisterGnssStatusCallback(gnssStatusCallback);
    }

    private static class GnssStatusCallback extends GnssStatus.Callback{

        WeakReference<MainActivity> activity;
        public GnssStatusCallback(MainActivity activity){

            this.activity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }
        @Override
        public void onSatelliteStatusChanged(GnssStatus status) {
            super.onSatelliteStatusChanged(status);

            //número de satélites
            int satelliteCount = status.getSatelliteCount();

            MainActivity activity = this.activity.get();
            if(activity != null) {

                Toast.makeText(activity,
                               "Satellite count = " + satelliteCount,
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                     .show();

                for(int i = 0; i < satelliteCount; i++){

                    //Obtenha informações especificas de cada satélite usando
                    //status.nomeMetodo(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito! Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Apenas complementando a resposta do @ramaral !

Implementação do  `GpsStatus.Listener`:

```
   class GPSStatusCallBack implements GpsStatus.Listener {

        @Override
        public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Servico.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            GpsStatus gpsStatus = locationManager.getGpsStatus(null);
            Iterator<GpsSatellite> satellites = gpsStatus.getSatellites().iterator();
            while (satellites.hasNext()){
                final GpsSatellite satellite = satellites.next();
                final StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder("");
                buff.append("\nAzimuth: "+satellite.getAzimuth());
                buff.append("\nElevation: "+satellite.getElevation());
                buff.append("\nPRN: "+satellite.getPrn());
                buff.append("\nSNR: "+satellite.getSnr());
                Log.w(TAG, buff.toString());

            }

        }
    }
```

Implementação do  `GnssStatus.Callback` :

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
class GnssStatusCallback extends GnssStatus.Callback{

    @Override
    public void onSatelliteStatusChanged(GnssStatus status) {

        int count = status.getSatelliteCount();

        Log.w(TAG, "Quantidade de satelites: "+count);
        for(int i = 0; i<count; i++){
            final StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder("");
            buff.append("\nAzimuthDegrees: "+status.getAzimuthDegrees(i));
            buff.append("\nConstellationType: "+status.getConstellationType(i));
            buff.append("\nCn0DbHz: "+status.getCn0DbHz(i));
            buff.append("\nElevationDegrees: "+status.getElevationDegrees(i));
            buff.append("\nSvid: "+status.getSvid(i));

            Log.w(TAG, buff.toString());
        }

    }
```

Chamado conforme versão:

```
 locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        locationManager.registerGnssStatusCallback(new GnssStatusCallback());
    }else{
        locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(new GPSStatusCallBack());
    }
```